# Weird shadows in arrayed floors in EEVEE

Tags: eevee-render-engine, lighting

When sun light is at particular angle.
These weird shadows appears between floors.
how can i fix this?
in cycle it doesn't happen.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to increase the quality of shadows in the Render Properties panel. Play with them until they look good. Also, try to make sure the surface area of your light is as small as possible if you want sharper shadows, the larger the surface area, the softer the shadows will be.
[image]